# Node.js - Using a callback function with Cheerio

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cheerio

I'm building a scraper in Node, which uses [request](https://github.com/request/request) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to load in pages and parse them.

It's important that I put a callback only AFTER Request and Cheerio has finished loading the page. I'm trying to use the [`async` extension](https://github.com/caolan/async), but I'm not entirely sure where to put the callback.

```
request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
    var $;
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error!: " + err + " using " + url);
    } else {
        async.series([
            function (callback) {
                $ = cheerio.load(body);
                callback();
            },
            function (callback) {
               // do stuff with the `$` content here
            }
        ]);
    }
});
```

I've been reading the [`cheerio documentation`](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) and can't find any examples of callbacks for when the content has been loaded in.

What's the best way to do it? When I throw 50 URLs at the script it starts moving on too early before cheerio has properly loaded in content, and I'm trying to curb any errors with async loading.

I'm totally new to asynchronous programming and callbacks in general so if I'm missing something simple here please let me know.

Comment: `cheerio.load` is a synchronous method as far as I can see so there's no need to use `async` for it. What do you mean by 'it starts moving on too early'? Do you perhaps want to limit/handle the calls to `request`?

Comment: By synchronous do you mean it's blocking? (I think that's the correct term...node will wait for it to complete?)

Comment: @robertklep Also to answer your question, when I was throwing lots of links at it I'd have strange things happening. I crated an object based on info scraped from a URL, and sometimes fields were missing, often all fields were missing. Am trying to build something that safeguards against this, the issue may just lie elsewhere though.

Comment: `load` is a bit of a misleading name, it should really be named `parse` or something. And yes, it's blocking. Depending on how you call `request`, you might be starting a whole bunch of requests simultaneously, which might be causing problems. Hard to tell without the context in which you call it, though :)

Comment: @robertklep gotcha, thanks for the help! Unfortunately it's quite a large script I've created (I'm trying to segment it and make it more modular at the moment) so it's not something I'm posting in full because god knows my question would be downvoted into oblivion :) Just trying to work out the kinks and weed out the problems. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `cheerio.load` is synchronous and you don't need any callbacks for it.

```
request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("Error!: " + err + " using " + url);
  }
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  // do stuff with the `$` content here
});
```