# call back on cheerio node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cheerio

I'm trying to write a **scraper** using 'request' and 'cheerio'. I have an array of 100 urls. I'm looping over the array and using 'request' on each url and then doing cheerio.load(body). If I increase i above 3 (i.e. change it to i < 3 for testing) the scraper breaks because var productNumber is undefined and I can't call split on undefined variable. I think that the for loop is moving on before the webpage responds and has time to load the body with cheerio, and this question: [nodeJS - Using a callback function with Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140589/nodejs-using-a-callback-function-with-cheerio) would seem to agree.

My problem is that I don't understand how I can make sure the webpage has 'loaded' or been parsed in each iteration of the loop so that I don't get any undefined variables. According to the other answer I don't need a callback, but then how do I do it?

```
for (var i = 0; i < productLinks.length; i++) {
    productUrl = productLinks[i];
    request(productUrl, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var imageUrl = $("#bigImage").attr('src'),
            productNumber = $("#product").attr('class').split(/\s+/)[3].split("_")[1]
        console.log(productNumber);

    });
};
```

Example of output:

```
1461536
1499543

TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Added to the question, can't call split of undefined. If I remove the split and just print out the imageUrl and/or the productNumber, some of the variables are set but a lot are undefined, which leads me to believe the loop is moving on before the webpage has responded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are scraping some external site(s). You can't be sure the HTML all fits exactly the same structure, so you need to be defensive on how you traverse it.

```
var product = $('#product');
if (!product) return console.log('Cannot find a product element');
var productClass = product.attr('class');
if (!productClass) return console.log('Product element does not have a class defined');
var productNumber = productClass.split(/\s+/)[3].split("_")[1];
console.log(productNumber);
```

This'll help you debug where things are going wrong, and perhaps indicate that you can't scrape your dataset as easily as you'd hoped.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not creating a new `$` variable for each iteration, it's being overwritten when a request is completed. This can lead to undefined behaviour, where one iteration of the loop is using `$` just as it's being overwritten by another iteration.

So try creating a new variable:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
^^^ this is the important part
```

Also, you are correct in assuming that the loop continues before the request is completed (in your situation, it isn't `cheerio.load` that is asynchronous, but `request` is). That's how asynchronous I/O works.

To coordinate asynchronous operations you can use, for instance, the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module; in this case, [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) might be useful.